# Tail an AWS CloudWatch Log Group

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Log Group that includes several Log Streams (from several EC2 instances). Is there any way to simply "tail" the consolidated logs in the group? If I click "Search Events" that shows the consolidated logs but the button that jumps to the end of the logs is grayed out. I have to manually plug in the date and time. I also tried the aws cli, but `aws logs get-log-events` requires a single log stream name to be specified.

Comment: I wish, but it doesn't seem to be available. You might consider a service like https://papertrailapp.com/ - I've used them and it's *awesome*.

Comment: awslogs should solve your problem quite nicely without introducing yet-another service in between you an your logs. (disclaimer: I'm the Author of awslogs) https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is now possible directly using AWS CLI v2. For example:

```
aws logs tail --since 1d --follow /aws/lambda/my_func
```

will tail and continuously watch CloudWatch logs from 1 day ago and forward into the future.

More here: https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/logs/tail.html

Answer (score 9):

A couple of command tools for a CloudWatch tail:

- https://github.com/jorgebastida/awslogs
- https://github.com/liamoehlman/cloudwatch-logs-tail

Answer (score 3):

I was really disappointed with `awslogs` and `cloudwatch-logs-tail` so I made my own tool called [Saw](https://github.com/TylerBrock/saw) that efficiently streams CloudWatch logs to the console (and colorizes the JSON output):

[image]

You can install it on MacOS with:

```
brew tap TylerBrock/saw
brew install saw
```

It has a bunch of nice features like the ability to automatically expand (indent) the JSON output (try running the tool with `--expand`):

```
saw watch my_log_group --expand
```

Got a Lambda you want to see error logs for? No Problem:

```
saw watch /aws/lambda/my_func --filter error
```

Saw is great because the output is easily readable and you can stream logs from entire log group, not just a single stream in the group. Filtering and watching streams with a certain prefix is also just as easy!

Comment: Thanks for building saw - looks interesting. Will try it out.